# Why is t used instead of delta t?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider a tank that holds $V$ liters of water. Let $x_0$ kg of salt be dissolved in the water at time $t_0$. Suppose that $V_o$ amount of the mixture is leaving the tank in every time interval, $\Delta t$. Based on the given information, we can write the following: 
$$\Delta x=-V_o\cdot \left(\frac{x}{V}\right)\cdot \Delta t$$ 
Now, suppose that as $V_o$ amount of the mixture is leaving the tank, $V_i$ liters of water is added to the tank. So, the change in volume of water in the tank is $\left(V_i-V_o\right)\cdot t$. Therefore:
$$\Delta x=-V_o\cdot \left(\frac{x}{V+\left(V_i-V_o\right)\cdot t}\right)\cdot \Delta t$$ 
My question is: why didn't we say the change in volume is $\left(V_i-V_o\right)\cdot \Delta t$ ? Why did we use $\Delta t$ in the first equation and not in the second one. How do we know when to use which?

Answer (score 0):

They're different because they refer to different intervals of time: one since the start of the experiment, and one advancing moment of time.

If you pour in $V_i = 1$ liter of water per second, and lose $V_o = 2$ liters of water per second, then the net flux is $V_i-V_0 = -1$ liter per second.  Therefore, to determine the amount of the water in the tank at any time, you must multiply this net flux by the time $t$ since the start of the experiment, and add the product to the original volume $V$.

In contrast, the equation as a whole has to do with the *momentary* (in the limit, instantaneous) change in salt content $\Delta x$ per moment (in the limit, instant) of time $\Delta t$, not the time since the start of the experiment.